# Enter should not send messages in mobile chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, mobile-web

Whenever I press enter, Stack Exchange sends the message I'm writing. Not uncommonly, this message is unfinished - I was going for period or backspace, and hit enter by accident. Dealing with half a message, often ending in a typo, can be kludgy.

This is also very nonstandard for Android interfaces. Every other messaging application I use waits for an explicit send press before actually sending a message. The reason is, well, exactly this.

I imagine it's not a particularly difficult change, either. There's already a send button in chat, which my intuition tells me to use. But chat not binding "send" to "enter" on mobile would be a huge help.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know the logic should go like this: for single-line entries, ENTER does do a Send, for multi-line entries it doesn't do a Send on ENTER, instead it goes to the next line.

So what is next is this: do we consider the chat message box as a single-line entry or not? For me it is. I understand this might be confusing when you use the chat on Android or iOS where there often is a separate Send button, but that might just be 'getting used to it'.

I am not particularly against it, but personally I don't see much benefit in this change, considering I never actually wanted ENTER not to do a Send.

Comment: You can't create a multi-line message on mobile if enter sends the message, unless you're copy/pasting from somewhere. This is to correct typos and accidental keystrokes _on mobile,_ not on web.

Comment: I got your point, but if the box is intended to be single-lined, as in this case, there is no loss of functionality. Correcting typos can be done with the edit option.

Comment: I see the point though, it's generally non-standard on Android to have the "Return/Enter" key as a submit button.  Generally for one-line entries, pressing Enter just removes focus from the textbox AFAIK.  It doesn't actually submit the content in the box usually, which is even more important on mobile devices where there isn't tactile feedback on button presses.  (I know I've submitted things by mistake on desktop by misclicking enter instead of shift)

Comment: I can agree with that, but it is not Android, it is web. Things are just different, animations, look and feel, etc. I have never considered that a problem. Do you suggest to change the ENTER key behavior based on the platform it runs on? That might get hard to implement. And it will cause inconsistency.

Comment: @Patrick Yes, I am suggesting changing the user interface to meet user expectations.